# Android virtual device does not take images from ldpi folder

Tags: android, resolution, screen-resolution

I have simple application that contains buttons with background image.

Applications have folders:

drawable-ldpi,
drawable-mdpi,
drawable-hdpi,
layout,
layout-small,
layout-large

When I design buttons for resolution 240*320 graphic layout (eclipse) show the image from drawable-ldpi folder, but when I strat virtual device 2.7 QVGA (240*320:ldpi) device show images from **drawable-mdpi** folder. The name of image is the same. I have no idea why virtual device show mdpi images. Is it posible that virtual device does this becouse I first select device with resolution 320X480 and run it and then change it to smaler (240*320:ldpi)?